# SVN Commit certificate issue

Tags: svn, cron, certificate, autocommit

I have a cronjob which commits some files every five minutes. However, it is not working anymore. It prints

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:443':
 - The certificate hostname does not match.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.xxxtest.com
 - Valid: from Jun  2 18:45:22 2010 GMT until Jul  4 15:59:29 2012 GMT
 - Issuer: Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, Equifax, US
 - Fingerprint: c1:34:e1:1c:2b:xx:2d:52:2a:xx:47:f9:5c:31:ad:fc:dd:02:db:xx
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx/svn/Kavrakoglu/trunk/CalismaAlani/Dataset/tjmkld874y2bfdb9149884yhndmkg5mk/VTIT080200BY13': Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname (https://xx.xx.xx.xx)
```

When I run this script manually, it gives no error and commits succesfully. What may be the cause of this problem and how can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: Is your cronjob running with a different user? Which client do you use? certificates have to be accepted once if the certificate is suspect, so sometimes you have to do some svn related once, and then you can use it in a script again. Perhaps your certificate has expired ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three options:

1. Get your network admins to issue an updated/correct certificate (the best option)
2. Change the command to `svn commit --non-interactive --trust-server-cert`
3. Sudo to root then change to whatever user is used by cron: `su cron_user` and then do a commit by hand.  You should get the above prompt and then you can choose option 'p' to accept permanently.

Comment: For routes 2. & 3. You need to make sure that the cron_user has an writable .subversion directory in its home directory, otherwise the 'p' accept is never stored